# IIS Rewrite - Remove real folder from the URL

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Please, I have this folder:

```
root/teste_seo/script.asp
```

Instead to use the url:

```
www.mysite.com/teste_seo/script.asp
```

I need this url using IIS rewrite:

```
www.mysite.com/script.asp
```

I try to use the rule from this link but didn't work:

[IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite - Rewrite a Folder from an URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615572/iis-7-5-url-rewrite-rewrite-a-folder-from-an-url)

Please, how can I write this rule?

PS.: For any *.asp file inside teste_seo folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following rule should do the trick:

```
<rule name="teste_seo" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^script.asp" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/teste_seo/script.asp" />
</rule>
```

Then just link to the www.mysite.com/script.asp

**Edited after comment from OP:**

If so you can use the following rule as long as you have a copy of the script files in the root of your document:

```
<rule name="teste_seo" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^teste_seo/([^\.]+\.asp)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

And if you need all script files to point to the same one you can use:

```
<rule name="teste_seo" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^teste_seo/([^\.]+\.asp)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/script.asp" />
</rule>
```

**Edited again after clarification:**

These 2 rules should then be the fix you need:

```
<rule name="teste_seo_redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^teste_seo/([^\.]+\.asp)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="teste_seo_rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^\.]+\.asp)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/teste_seo/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Hi Siggi2k! Tks! Sorry but I forget to write that I need for any *.asp file inside teste_seo folder. From abc.asp to xyz.asp.

Comment: Do you need all scripts that are in the teste_seo folder to work on the root level?

Do you need www.mysite.com/teste_seo/script.asp to point to www.mysite.com/script.asp and then www.mysite.com/teste_seo/another-script.asp to point to www.mysite.com/another-script.asp?


I Edited my original answer with the code that i think will help you, so please mark it as an answer if this solved your problem.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But, I need to have the copy of all files inside teste_seo folder in root folder? You said "as long as you have a copy of the script files in the root"

Comment: I see, i misunderstood, but i have edited my answer with what i think will be your solution.

Comment: Thank you my friend! Tha's exactly what I was looking for.